# Event listeners in this Rock–Paper–Scissors game is unable to select the correct array value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom-events

I’m creating a Rock–Paper–Scissors game in JS.

Problem: The `playerChooses` function is unable to select the correct array value in `choices`.

- `rock_btn` corresponds to `choices[0]` or `'Rock'`
- `paper_btn` corresponds to `choices[1]` or `'Paper'`
- `scissors_btn` corresponds to `choices[2]` or `'Scissors'`

Expected output:

- When `rock_btn` is clicked `player.currentChoice = choices[0];`
- When `paper_btn` is clicked `player.currentChoice = choices[1];`
- When `scissors_btn` is clicked `player.currentChoice = choices[2];`

Actual output:

- When `rock_btn` is clicked `player.currentChoice = choices[0];`
- When `paper_btn` is clicked `player.currentChoice = choices[0];`
- When `scissors_btn` is clicked `player.currentChoice = choices[0];`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/alokj/pen/XWgJXKY?editors=1111).

```js
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
}
const choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

// Try changing the line below to test out the conditional!
player.currentChoice = choices[2];

const rock_btn = document.querySelector(".rock_btn");
const paper_btn = document.querySelector(".paper_btn");
const scissors_btn = document.querySelector(".scissors_btn");

function playerChooses(){ 
  if (rock_btn.click) {
    player.currentChoice = choices[0];
    console.log("Player chooses " + player.currentChoice);     
  }
  else if (paper_btn.click) { 
    player.currentChoice = choices[1];
    console.log("Player chooses " + player.currentChoice); 
  }
  else if (scissors_btn.click) { 
    player.currentChoice = choices[2];
    console.log("Player chooses " + player.currentChoice); 
  }
  else { 
    console.log("Unknown error in playerChoooses")
  }
}

rock_btn.addEventListener('click', playerChooses);
paper_btn.addEventListener('click', playerChooses);
scissors_btn.addEventListener('click', playerChooses);

function computerChooses() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  
  computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
}

// Here, we removed the console.logs, and instead, stored the message in the displayResult function. We'll declare the displayResult function later, which we'll use to add the text to the HTML.
function compareChoices() {
  computerChooses();
  //playerChooses();
  
  if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
    displayResult("It's a tie! The computer and player both chose " + computer.currentChoice);
  }
  else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
    else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  }
  else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
    else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  }
  else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
    else {
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }
  }
}

// The displayResult function creates a new paragraph element, called resultText, that adds the results from the compareChoices function above.
function displayResult(result) {
  const resultContainer = document.querySelector('.winner_notification');
  const resultText = document.querySelector('.winner');
  const playerSelectionResult = document.querySelector('.player_choice');
  const computerSelectionResult = document.querySelector('.computer_choice');
  
  resultText.innerText = result;
  playerSelectionResult.innerText = player.currentChoice;
  computerSelectionResult.innerText = computer.currentChoice;
  console.log(resultText);
  resultContainer.append(resultText);
}

// Don't forget to call the function to make the game run!
compareChoices();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    <h4>Who Won</h4>
    <p class="winner_notification">
      <span class="winner"></span>
    </p>
    <table class="winner_leaderboard">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Your Choice</td>
          <td>Computer's Choice</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td class="player_choice">None</td>
        <td class="computer_choice">None</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <h4>Make a selection</h4>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <td class="rock_td">
          <button name="rock" class="rock_btn">Rock</button>
        </td>
        <td class="paper_td">
          <button name="paper" class="paper_btn">Paper</button>
        </td>
        <td class="scissors_td">
          <button name="scissors" class="scissors_btn">Scissors</button>
        </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `if(rock_btn.click)` is exactly the same as `if(true)`. `rock_btn.click` is a function that allows programmatic clicking. Get the event argument: `function playerChooses(event){`…`}`, then `event.target` will tell you which button was clicked.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+check+which+button+was+clicked) of [Determine which button was clicked inside a div](/q/30499447/4642212).